# Flutter audio_service plugin: Error: JS interop class 'MediaMetadata' conflicts with natively supported class 'MediaMetadata' in 'dart:html'

Tags: flutter, audio, flutter-web

I'm making a Flutter app that uses the audio_service plugin. It works on Android, iOS and macOS. However when I run it on the web with Chrome I get the following error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/audio_service-0.16.1/lib/js/media_metadata.dart:7:7: Error: JS interop class 'MediaMetadata' conflicts with natively supported class 'MediaMetadata' in 'dart:html'.
class MediaMetadata {
      ^
Failed to compile application.
```

How do I work around this error before [the issue](https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/issues/574) is solved?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of running your app from the IDE, run it from the command line:

```
flutter run -d chrome
```

This worked for me and was also reported to work [here](https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/issues/574#issuecomment-753519548).